# Find right order of numbers - Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, greedy

I am working on a solution that as below:
I have 2 unsorted lists and need to find a way that can give me a value comparing the numbers from the first list to the second list.
the rules are as follows:
- A player can fight against a single-player only
- A player can win only when his/her power is strictly greater than the opponent's power

Input Format
- The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T
- The first line of each test case consists of the number of members each team can have, N.
- The second line of each test case consists of N space-separated integers representing the power of first-team
- The third line of each test case consists of N space-separated integers representing the power of second team

I have written code as follows:

```
def get_info(n,tg,op):
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(len(op)):
            if tg[i]>op[j]:
                cnt+=1
                op.pop(j)                
                break    
    return cnt

def main():
    t=int(input())
    l = []
    for i in range(t):
        n=int(input())
        tg=list(map(int,input().split()))
        op=list(map(int,input().split()))    
        # cnt=0
        tg.sort(reverse=True)    
        op.sort(reverse=True)
        res = get_info(n,tg,op)
        l.append(res)
    print(*l,sep='\n')


main()
```

The input and output is as follows:

```
1
10
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1
2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
7
```

The constraints are as follows:

Constraints
1<= T <=100000 1<= N <=100000
0<= Power of Beyblade <= LLONG_MAX

I was able to pass through most of the test cases, but when it comes larger list the program fails with time lime exceeding

Can this be solved with Bisect or two pointer in Python for better results?

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

You are looping unnecessary each time from the beginning of the list. Suppose your lists looks like this:

```
[12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 4] #tg
[13, 13, 13, 2, 1, 0] #op
```

For the 12 you loop till 2 in the second list. For the 11 you loop until 1 and for the 10 you loop until 0. Though you have popped the element, you compare 12,11,10 with all 13s, which are 9 comparisons.
Since you already know that the 13 > 12, there is no need to compare 11 or 10 with 13 saving you 6 comparisons. That is because you sorted and know each following number will be smaller than any number left from the last element of the op list.

Knowing that, you can take advantage by saving unnecessary comparisons by starting from the next element of the op list:

```
from itertools import islice
def get_info(n,tg,op):
    cnt = 0
    start_index = 0
        for index, tg_element in enumerate(tg):
            for op_element in islice(op,start_index,None):
                start_index += 1
                if tg_element > op_element:
                    cnt += 1
                    break    
    return cnt
```

The complexity of your algorithm was unnecessarily in O(n^2).

Comment: i guess this has solved the complexity of the algorithm. But for large inputs, its taking more than 4 seconds to execute. Unfortunately, I do not have the test cases @David